# How can i show descendants of tagged revision excluding the tag?

Tags: mercurial

With the command

```
hg log --rev "descendants(last(tagged()))"
```

I get a list of all changesets from the last tag *including* the tagged changeset. How can I exclude the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
descendants(children(last(tagged())))
```

`last(tagged())` gives you the tag changeset.
and children returns direct child (or children) of that tagged changeset.

leaving `descendants` to return all the descendant children of tags child.